# BindingSource.Filter: Combining Multiple Filters C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2010, bindingsource

I am writing a program that hooks into an Access Database.  I have 3 search criteria I am attempting to combine. Two of the filters are derived from checkboxes, while the 3rd is a searchbox. Individually these 3 work great.  However, when attempting to Concatenate the filters it seems to only recognize the 'CheckedSListFilter'.  I have tested multiple iterations of the concatenated string without any luck.  I'm hoping this is just a syntax issue.  Thanks for your help.

```
        string SFilter = CheckedSListFilter();// method returns string "S = 'w1' OR S = 'w2' OR S = 'w3'"
        string PFilter = CheckedPStatusFilter();//method returns string "PA = 'True' OR "PB = 'True'"
        string CFilter = comboBox_SearchFields.Text;
        string filter = CFilter + " LIKE '" + "*" + textBox_search.Text + "*" + "'";//returns "R LIKE '*g*'"

                BindingSource bs = this.projectBindingSource;
                bs.Filter =  filter+" AND "+"("+PFilter +" OR "+SFilter+")";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this on my own.  Order of operations was tripping me up.  Ended up doing something like this:  bs.Filter = "("+SFilter+")"+" AND "+"("+PFilter+")"+" AND "+"("+PFilter+")";
All now works as expected.