# bindingsource.filter how to add multiple filters from different columns

Tags: c#, datatable, bindingsource

I'm learning/trying to add multiple filters from different columns in a `DataTable`. I am able to filter for a single value using a string like `name = 'john'` where name is the column header and 'john' is the item to filter for and I am able to add a second filter on the same column which ends up looking like:

`bindingSource.Filter = "name = 'john' OR name = 'jane'"`

Let's say I have a datatable that looks like the following:

```
**name** | **country** // column headers
john     | USA
jose     | Mexico
jane     | USA
```

I am now trying to filter for multiple terms from different columns. I have tried a string like this `"name = 'john' AND country = 'USA'"` but the datatable shows nothing.

I have also tried `"name = 'john' OR country = 'USA'"` but this doesn't seem to do anything.

I have looked at other SO posts and links on the web but I haven't found anything that addresses the issue I am having.

Here are a couple of links I have checked so far:

[this link](https://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)

[this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter?view=net-5.0)

[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499013/bindingsource-filter-combining-multiple-filters-c-sharp-winforms)

Any and all help/direction is appreciated.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue using [this code](https://pastebin.com/qX6vt6hF) but it filters correctly. Can you provide more details about how you're using this?

Comment: I've also used the `BindingSource` as a `DataSource` for a `DataGridView` and can confirm it filters correctly.

Comment: can you paste class definition of the bound item type?

Comment: I'm probably not using it correctly then. will post code shortly.

Comment: I figured it out. turns out I had used `.TrimEnd()` to trim a trailing "\r" in the process earlier. when I adjusted the filter to include that, the proper results started showing up. Thank you guys for your help.